# What are the conditions for holding or touching the Qur’an?

Tags: quran, fiqh, reading-quran

What are the conditions for holding or touching the Qur’an  please explain clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only condition is that you must be pure. Meaning you should have done wuzu (ablution) and ghusl (bath) if you needed to do that, i.e. not be in state of impurity due to junub (after orgasm) or haiz (menses) etc. Also being a Muslim is a condition for same reason.

> None touch it except the purified. ([Surat Al-Wāqi`ah 79](https://legacy.quran.com/56/79))